# php find dom element by containing text and adding an attribute

Tags: php

i have following html code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
          var text = "this is just an example";
      </script>
      <? MPage::PlaceHolder("scipts") ?>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div>
             <? MPage::PlaceHolder("menu") ?>
        </div>
        <span>
             <? MPage::PlaceHolder("content") ?>
             <? MPage::PlaceHolder("footer") ?>
        </span>
   </body>
</html>
```

what i wan't is to find all the element containing  MPage::PlaceHolder(...) and add an attribute called mpage-placeholder="..." in **PHP**, before outputting it

so:

```
<div>
   <? MPage::PlaceHolder("menu") ?>
</div>
```

becomes:

```
<div mpage-placeholder="menu">
   <? MPage::PlaceHolder("menu") ?>
</div>
```

is this even possible??

cheers
c_bb

Comment: Yes, but there might be a better solution. What is your end-goal in doing so?

Comment: it is to have a consistency in my php code, i'm loading my page to start with using mpage, then on run time i load some modules with html code, I need to know where to put the content of the module, and keep the setup of the php the same ... can you share the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Using PHP, you should make it a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and then use [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). This returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), which is basically an array of DOMElement objects in this case. Now you can traverse the elements that contain that value. Using a wildcard `('*')` in the getElements method returns a traversable DOMNodeList from which then the values of alle Nodes can be examined. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$input ='<html>...</html>'; // HTML contents in string

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input); // Convert HTML String into DOMDocument

$allNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*'); // Get all DOMElements
foreach($allNodes as $node)
    {
    // If the node contains the value you want
    if (strpos($node->nodeValue, "MPage::PlaceHolder") !== false)
    { 
        // Give the node an attribute
        $node->setAttribute("mpage-placeholder", "menu");
        // If need be you can give the node's parent the attribute:
        $node->parentNode->setAttribute("mpage-placeholder", "menu");
    }

}
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$xmlDoc = $xmlDoc->saveHTML(); // Write DOMDocument back into a String
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start an output buffer (with `ob_start`) at the begining of the script in order to capture the outputted text.

When `MPage::PlaceHolder()` function is called you may obtain the outputted text (with `ob_get_contents`, for example) and then analyze the outputted HTML in order to find the changes you want to do.

If any changes have been made you may use `ob_clean` to clean the buffer (but not delete it) and then print the modified HTML.

I don't consider this very efficient, but it may work for you.

**EDIT:**

Another idea is to perform whatever operations (other than adding HTML attributes) the funciton does, plus adding some special tag: for example:

```
<!-- MPAGE:SOMETHING -->
```

Thus at the end of the code you may search all these tags and perform the search for the parent node. This search you can become very simple if you put the PHP right after the tag is open.

**EDIT 2**

Just for fun, this regular expresion finds the last unclosed html tag:

```
preg_match("/.*<((?![\\/?])[^>]+[^\\/])>(?!.*<\\/\\1>).*?$/s", $html, ...)
```

It can be used with the first method I proposed.

Comment: that is what i'm doing ... the issue is when i load my modules via ajax on client side, i need an identifier in the html code so i know where to put the data!

Comment: You need to edit the html you obtain from the funciton call to `ob_get_contents`.

Comment: Say, you may be able to use the parameter you pass to `MPage::PlaceHolder()` to simplify what you need to search. For example,:

<? MPage::PlaceHolder("scipts") ?>

Should search for the last ocurrence of <head>  and add the HTML attribute you want to add.

On the other hand, custom named attributes in HTML must start with data- (data-placeholder for example).

Comment: I understand what you are saying ... but don't like that solution, there has to be a dynamic way of doing it, what if i decide to have a scripts placeholder in the span ... then the whole thing does not work because it is looking for head or it puts it in head, where it is not supposed to go!

Comment: "When MPage::PlaceHolder() function is called you may obtain the outputted text" .... still don't know which is the parent node this way!

Comment: You may not know what the parent node is, but you have every tool to find it. I believe what you ask is some kind of pre-parsing of php code. Maybe you should try replacing the PHP with some kind of speical tag you devise and analyze the HTML as a whole to find parents with absolute cerntainty (which could be more efficient than the previously indicated method). I'll edit the solution with this idea.